# Reading .txt file. How would I go about just reading a whole string(ignoring spaces) & assigning it to on variable?

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

So I have a file called "stock.txt" that a couple of stocks in the format:(symbol) (Name of the Stock) (Price) (date) each of different lines. Only the date is separated by a tab. So this is how it reads my data:

```
try {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("stock.txt"));
    while(input.hasNext()) {

        String symbol = input.next();
        String name = input.next();
        String price = input.next();
        String date = input.next();


        Stock newStock = new Stock(symbol, name, price, date);
        myStocks.add(newStock);
    }

}
```

but just noticed that if my text reads "IBM International Business Machines 144.84 --tab-- 5/2/16" the following get assigned `symbol = IBM`, `name = International` `price = Business` & `date = Machines` since it assigns the next string to the next variable. How would I go about just reading the whole name is assigning it to `name`? I know the flaw is how I am reading my .txt file, but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Get each line from the file one at a time within the while loop, and then work on the line. Note that you can use other things to split a String including `String#split(...)` a method that uses regex.

Answer (score 1):

2 approaches ----

1)
Not the best of solutions i must confess but works..

you can create an array of all the values from each line

```
          for (int i =0 ; input.hasNext(); i++)
          {

            array.add(input.next());
          }
```

And once you have the array of all values then specific to your file you could set something like this

```
array[0] = symbol;
String name = "";
for (i=1, i < array.length -2, i++ ) {
      name = array[i] + " "
}
String price = array[array.size -2]
String date = array[array.size -1]
```

You can modify to use your object setters and getters for the same.

2) If you could add a symbol to your text file which represents an end of the particular field . Maybe something lik
e ';'. You could use the separators to get the next in line.